# Travelling Salesman Problem on the unit sphere

Tags: combinatorics, spherical-geometry

Let vertices be defined on the unit sphere by its longitudes $\lambda_i$ and latitudes $\phi_i$. The distance between $i$ and $j$ is defined as follows: $\arccos(\sin(\lambda_i) \sin(\lambda_j) \cos(\phi_i - \phi_j) + \cos(\lambda_i) \cos(\lambda_j))$ which is an angle measure of the shortest distance between two points on unit sphere.

So, I want solve the traveling salesman problem on this unit sphere. Unfortunately, I didn't found any information on this problem.

Are there any approximations, heuristics, etc which utilize this distance definition?

Comment: What's the difference to doing it in the plane? (Errh, I mean solving the TSP)

Comment: @draks, the difference is that plane is open set instead of surface of a sphere.

Comment: But, after you calculated all the distances and put them in an adjacency matrix nobody will recognize the sphere anymore, right?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for "spherical TSP" one finds a number of resources on this problem. For example, Ben Nolting's blog post [A Traveling Salesman on a Sphere: Pitbull's Arctic Adventure](http://datavoreconsulting.com/programming-tips/a-traveling-salesman-on-a-sphere-pitbulls-arctic-adventure/) contains Mathematica-based solution. I quote the main steps here:

```
positionVec[{u_, v_}] := {Cos[v °] Cos[u °], Sin[v °] Cos[u ° ], Sin[u °]};
distance[{u1_,v1_},{u2_,v2_}] := VectorAngle[ positionVec[{u1,v1}], positionVec[{u2,v2}]];
tour=FindShortestTour[citylocations, DistanceFunction->distance]
```

Comment: This is more of a guide on how to do this in Mathematica, which says nothing about the algorithm used; it just uses some algorithm implemented in Mathematica, which presumably is some generic algorithm rather than some heuristic specific for spherical geometry, which the question was about (if I read correctly, it does not even know that the data comes from spherical geometry, the input is just distances).